# No se insertan los datos en la BBDD

Tags: python, django

Estoy trabajando con `Django`, y quiero insertar unos valores en la base de datos, pero no se insertan y no emite ningún error.

A partir de un producto seleccionado, intento mostrarle al usuario un formulario que muestre el producto seleccionado, le permita seleccionar en un `select` la ueb y especificar la cantidad que desea distribuir de ese producto previamente seleccionado a la ueb especificada. (Entiéndase como ueb, puede ser una entidad).

Éste es mi código:

**models:**

```
class Distrib_Productos(models.Model):
    nombre_UEB = models.ForeignKey(UEB)
    productos = models.ForeignKey(Producto)
    cantidad_a_asignar = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nombre_UEB
```

**form:**

```
class Distrib_ProductosForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Distrib_Productos
```

views

```
def realizar_distribucion(request, id):
    producto = Producto.objects.get(id=id)
    uebs = UEB.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('administrador/inserciones/distribucion_productos.html',
                              {'action': 'realizardistribucion/' + id, 'producto': producto, 'uebs': uebs},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )


def realizardistribucion(request, id):
    producto = Producto.objects.get(id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        cantidad = request.POST['cantidad']
        uebs = request.POST.getlist('nombre_UEB')
        for ueb in uebs:
            distribucion =  Distrib_Productos.objects.get_or_create(nombre_UEB=ueb,
                                                                        productos=producto,
                                                                   cantidad_a_asignar = cantidad)

    return realizar_distribucion(request,id)
```

**html**

```
 <div id="style">
        <form method="post" id="style_admin2" action="/{{ action }}/">{% csrf_token %}
            <table>

                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><label id="prod">Producto</label></td>

                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="productos" value="{{ form.productos}}"
                               class="form-control" id="contactos3"
                               placeholder="{{ producto.nombre }}">
                    </td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                     <td colspan="2"><p class="help-block" >    * Debes seleccionar la UEB a la que le asignarás el producto</p></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label id="prod">Nombre de UEB</label></td>
                    <td>
                        <select>
                            {% for ueb in uebs %}
                                <option name="nombre_UEB" value="{{ ueb.id}}">{{ ueb.nombre }}</option>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </select>

                    </td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label id="prod">Disponibilidad</label></td>
                  <td>
                      <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="texto_distrib">
                      <thead>
                          <th id="detalles_distrib">Cantidad en Almacén</th>
                            <th id="detalles_distrib">Tipo de Movimiento</th>
                            <th id="detalles_distrib">Precio CUP</th>
                            <th id="detalles_distrib">Precio CUC</th>
                       </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td id="detalles_distrib">{{ producto.cantidad }}</td>
                            <td id="detalles_distrib">{{ producto.tipo_movimiento }}</td>
                            <td id="detalles_distrib">{{ producto.precio_CUP }}</td>
                            <td id="detalles_distrib">{{ producto.precio_CUC }}</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                  </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><label id="prod">Cantidad a Asignar</label></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="cantidad" class="form-control" id="contactos3"
                               placeholder="cantidad a asignar"></td>
                </tr>

                </tbody>

            </table>

            <button id="buscar" type="submit" class="btn  btn-primary"><strong>Aceptar</strong></button>

        </form>

    </div>
```

Comment: Debes explicar un poco más, como por ejemplo que errores te da al insertar?

Comment: Hola. El sitio tiene unas normas. Por ejemplo, el título no es para saludar, es para hacer una pregunta descriptiva sobre tu problema. En el cuerpo de la pregunta no indicas qué problema obtienes, ni donde, no muestras un error, ni indicas que tipo de BBDD usas, ni si estamos hablando de Django, Flask,... Por favor, edita la pregunta aportando mayor información.

Comment: Cómo dice @AdrianaHernández y kikocorreoso no está claro lo que estás preguntando, da más detalles de tu pregunta apra poder ayudarte mejor :) Un saludo

Comment: no me emite ningun error solo no me inserta los datos en la base de datos, trabajo con django. A partir de un producto seleccionado,intento mostrarle al usuario un formulario que muestre el producto seleccionado, le permita seleccionar en un select la ueb y especificar la cantidad que desea distribuir de ese producto previamente seleccionado a la ueb especificada.(entiendase como ueb,puede ser una entidad).Saludos...

Comment: Podrías darnos mas información sobre la base de datos que usas,  la configuración de la misma en django. Tal vez chequea tu conexión con la db. Muchos factores pueden inferir en lo que necesitas pero danos as información-

Comment: uso mysql,pero he creado otras vistas que hacen consulta a la base de datos y si me funciona,creo que es problema a la hora de tratar con la variable que me recoge por post las uebs,porque ya he probado pasandole un objeto ueb y si mi inserta.

Comment: Amigos...muchas gracias ya he encontrado la solucion muy simple y las quiero compartir con ustedes... en el html solo faltaba ponerle en el html,en el select el mismo atributo name

Comment: Yo lo que haría en primer lugar, comprobar en la vista si el form es válido
`form.is_valid()`, y en segundo lugar, incluir en el template la lista de errores `form.errors`. A partir de ahí tendrías una pista para saber que puede estar ocurriendo.